# iframe sandbox is not caching my JS script

Tags: html, iframe, browser, http-caching

I can't seem to cache my JS files.

A simple test:

**index.html**

```html
<iframe src="iframe.html" sandbox="allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

**iframe.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src s3.objectstorage.com;" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="http://s3.objectstorage.com/blah.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I change the sandbox attribute to include `allow-same-origin`, caching begins to work.  However, I will be loading untrusted JS files, so I cannot allow that.

What are my options, so that my JS files are cached?

**Update 1**
Looks like I might be forced to download my raw JS from parent into an html blob, then reference the blob url for the iframe.  Doesn't seem elegant, but will attempt tomorrow.

**Update 2**
There does not seem to be an adequate solution for loading within the iframe.  I had to generate an html file with the script injected.  Then, I load the html file in the iframe src.  This does a disk cache, which seems to be sufficient for my purposes, and keep the iframe security.

Comment: can't you manually store scripts using `localStorage`?

Comment: @TheBombSquad
It didn't seem possible to download from a domain outside of my own and store inside a blob or localStorage.  And hosting my own proxy to keep it same origin for file downloads would cost too much bandwidth.  I opt'd for an alternate solution in my Update 2.

Comment: i mean u talk about caching scripts.. so, u can loop through `document.all` and store the `innerHTML` of all elements that have the `tagName` called `"SCRIPT"` stored in an array inside localStorage

Comment: Note this is only true in chrome, not firefox. I don't see any documentation that imply files shouldn't be cached. I've reported this as a chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1500357

Comment: @ChrisHamilton nice.  Sadly, I don't think Chrome will fix.  The origin is basically null, so there is no caching bucket for it to be stored.  The solution is to use `allow-same-origin` but store the iframe .html file on a different domain like an object storage, routed through a subdomain.  This blocks users from using JS to access parent.

Comment: Makes sense, but Firefox seems to have a solution so there is hope.